# PHP Datetime object serialization

Tags: php, datetime, serialization

I have a web API and locally the datetime object is serialized like this:

```
"timeInsert":{"date":"2014-12-09 01:15:19","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/Ljubljana"}
```

When I deploy the application online on a server, the datetime is serialized like this:

```
"timeInsert":{"date":"2014-12-09 01:15:19.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/Ljubljana"}
```

Note the appended **.000000** (microseconds). Both servers (local inside Vagrant and live) run on Linux Ubuntu 12.04.

Date command on both servers outputs the same: Mon Dec 22 08:20:28 UTC 2014 and both have PHP version 5.5.x (x differs a little bit).

What could be the reason the datetime is serialized different on both systems? I would like the date without microseconds. Thanks in advance!:)

Comment: It's not the php serialization format. What do you mean by 'serialized'?

Comment: I use json_encode on the datetime object. I can manually get the desired format with format method, but I really wonder why the same code on mostly the same systems outputs different at the moment.

Comment: It dependences on PHP version: http://3v4l.org/pKPcJ

Comment: Thank you sectus, that is exactly what I needed. The php version is exactly what looks like is causing the problem. You can write an answer so I an accept it:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior dependencies on PHP version and relayed on PHP bug: [#67308 Serialize of DateTime truncates fractions of second](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67308) - https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-5.6.4/NEWS#L902

Simple script to check

```
echo  json_encode(new DateTime('@1419237113'));
```

http://3v4l.org/pKPcJ